# NGINX abruptly stopped working after system restart

Tags: nginx

I'm using Rocky Linux. My NGINX setup randomly stopped working after having previously worked perfectly for months, now all of my reverse proxy sites don't work anymore. I receive an `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` in my browser when I try to go to the websites. If I `nslookup` the sites, it does return the correct IP, so my DNS isn't wrong.

I've tried restarting the system, checking the config files, restarting NGINX, restarting the other services, but nothing works. I can still connect to all of the services using an `ip:port`, so those services aren't down, and all of them have worked through NGINX previously. This leads me to believe the issue is with NGINX itself instead of the other services. I've also tried disabling SELinux, that didn't help either.

I'm sure I'll need to provide logs, but I'm not sure which logs to provide. If you need any to help out, let me know and I'll grab them.

Edit: Here's my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

Edit 2: Here's my updated `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file (since posting I've updated NGINX and regenerated this file).

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147759/discussion-on-question-by-seaswimmerthefsh-nginx-abruptly-stopped-working-after); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @Kusalananda You moved ALL comments to chat whether they met the comment requirements. 
YOU didn't bother to help answer or help. 
If this is how pedantic the site is going to become I'm out. Cheers.

Comment: @Csnap I did indeed move all comments to chat. I did that as a response to an automatic moderator flag that was raised due to the length of the comment thread. The comments are still readily available [in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147759/discussion-on-question-by-seaswimmerthefsh-nginx-abruptly-stopped-working-after) into which they were moved.